# LinQToSql and Hashtable using the same DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, data-binding, datatemplate

I am using LinQToSql and a Hashtable(System.Collections) they both use the same GridView, the datacontext will be changed depending on the Checkbox. Only onee of them is active.

The prpblem is ,that the hashtable(just key value) has a different structure than than the LinqToSql class.

This works fine for the LinQToSql class(DataContext):

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="wordListView" Margin="17,156,0,0"
VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}">
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image"  IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image  Height="200"  Source="{Binding Path}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path,Converter={StaticResource stringReplacer}}">   
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Path" Binding="{Binding Path}">
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I would love to use 1 GridView, but with different data.

I thought of this( can not make it work):

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="fromDB">
            //using the DataGrid.Columns for LINQToSQL
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="fromFile">
           //just use binding, or a different DataGrid.Columns
        </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: You talked about different data, so how exactly they are different? they just contain different records but the item type should be the same (so that the Bindings won't be broken between switches)?

Comment: The hashtable(has a "key" and a "value")(should be the column header), the DataContext(has "ID", "Path" and "TimeStamp"), if I use my switch the datagrid will show all the rows but they are empty, but the number of records is correct ,it looks like this [link](http://postimg.org/image/8izukrt31/)